# how to run a series of 'function' tests, sequentially, with nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have one really long function tests, that starts from the login panel of my web application and goes all the way through deeper features. It is my first time using nightwatch.js - I'm wondering if there is a way to break this huge function up, into multiple, segmented functions, that run sequentially. I tried, literally breaking it up into separate functions, just like my main, large one, I also tried wrapping each separated function in between `'browser'` and `'browser.end();'` but this also did not work - what happens is, they don't run sequentially - so of course they don't find the next underlying elements, etc. because it starts over. Any advice?

```
    this.LoginScreen = function(browser) {
            browser
                    .url(Data.urls.home)
                    .waitForElementVisible('#login', 1000, false)
                    .click('#login')
                    .waitForElementVisible('div.side-panel.open', 4000, false)
                    // Ton more here, i'd like to modulate 

        Errors.checkForErrors(browser);

        browser.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple and available in Nightwatch Getting Started Page http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted

```
module.exports = {
 'Verify Added customer': function (browser) {
// In above first function with name 'Verify Added customer'
    browser
    .click(rc.registeredCustomers)
    .pause(t.averagePauseLimit)

},

'Verify Email Button Present': function (browser) {
// in above there is second function
    browser
        .click(rc.registeredCustomers)
        .pause(t.averagePauseLimit)
        .getText(rc.primaryEmail, function (result) {
            this.assert.equal(result.value, 'Primary : ' + email)
        })
        .pause(t.minimumPauseLimit)
        .click(rc.verifyCustomer)
        .pause(1000)
        .assert.elementNotPresent(rc.verifyEmail, 'Verify Email is not present')


},
```

Comment: when you execute the above file the functions execute sequentially

Comment: To run tests sequentially, in your nightwatch.conf.js, comment out the "test_worker" tag:                                        
  //"test_workers": { "enabled": true, "workers": 1}                                                                                 More info: https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/parallel-running.html